# "Operation cancelled by user" (but I didn't!)

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was playing around with the Data Explorer, and formulated the following query (this is not an SQL question; it is about the Data Explorer):

```
SELECT TOP 2000
  P.Id as [Post Link],
  P.Score as [Post Score],
  C.Id as [Comment Link],
  C.Score as [Comment Score]
FROM Posts as P INNER JOIN Comments as C
  ON P.Id = C.PostId
WHERE C.Score > P.Score
ORDER BY
  C.Score DESC,
  P.Score DESC
```

I then attempted to test-drive the query. It appeared to hang for a little while, then produced the following error:

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation cancelled by user.

*I didn't cancel it...*

**Note:** The query completes normally if I change `TOP 2000` to `TOP 1000`. Was it an overheated server kitty cancelling my query because it was too resource-intensive?

(If it helps, I was testing on the SO data.)

Comment: That's just the error thrown from the database, it doesn't really mean you as user of Data Explorer site canceled anything.